# launch activity while ConfirmationActivity is displayed

Tags: wear-os

I have an activity that launches a confirmationActivity onclick(). I want that, while the confirmation activity is displayed, a new activity is launched so that when the confirmation activity ends, the new activity is displayed.

```
@Override
public void onTimerFinished(View view) {
    //delayed confirmation
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), ConfirmationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
            ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
            "Run Saved!");
    startActivity(intent);

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), WearUploadRunActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    mResults.finishIt();

    end = true;
}
```

my code is like this atm. In this case, the confirmation activity is not displayed because the parent activity(mResults) is killed before it is displayed... 
Can someone help me with this issue? I just want to activity **A** launch **confirmationActivity** and then when the **confirmationactivity** ends the activity **B** is displayed.

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void onTimerSelected(View v) {
    if (animation == false) {
        mDelayedView.start();
        mDelayedView.setListener(this);
        animation = true;
    } else {
        mDelayedView.reset();
        animation = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't start both activities as you are doing there. You should start your ConfirmationActivity and then, you can use the callbacks `onTimerFinished()` or `onTimerSelected()` of the [ConfirmationActivity](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html) to trigger the start of the second activity.

Comment: The thing is that I need to wait till onTimerFinished to start the confirmation activity. I cant start the new activity right after the timer is selected because the user can cancel his action by clicking the button again. Can you please provide more information about your solution?